# Check if an Edge is already in std::vector (speed-up)

Tags: c++, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

I have some code that works, but it spends most of the time in this function, being extremely inefficient.

Overall task: get MST that includes the shortest path between specified vertices.

```
void MSTPath::m_add_shortest_path(vector<Edge> path){
    for (Edge e : path) m_graph->union_vu(e.get_node(),e.get_opposite_node(-1));

    for (Edge e : m_all_edges){
        if (MSTPath::m_in_path(e,path)) m_mst.push_back(e);
        else m_edges.push_back(e);
}
```

What does this function do: adds all the Edges from `vector<Edge> path` (a shortest path in the graph) to the MST, so that the computed MST includes this path. All the other Edges it ads to `m_edges`, which is a vector of "candidates" for the edges in the MST.

```
bool MSTPath::m_in_path(Edge edge, vector<Edge> path){
    for (Edge e : path){
        if ((e.get_node()==edge.get_node()) && (e.get_opposite_node(-1)==edge.get_opposite_node(-1)))
            return true;
    }
```

How it then looks for computing MST:

```
int MSTPath::m_compute_mst(){
    sort(m_edges.begin(),m_edges.end(),[](Edge e1, Edge e2) { return e1.weight < e2.weight; });
    int i = 0;
    int mst_size = m_mst.size();
    int mst_weight = 0;
    int v,u;
    for (Edge e : m_mst) mst_weight += e.weight;
    while (mst_size<m_N-1){
        Edge edge = m_edges[i++];
        v = m_graph->find(edge.get_node());
        u = m_graph->find(edge.get_opposite_node(-1));
        if (u!=v){
            mst_size++;
            mst_weight += edge.weight;
            if (mst_weight>=min_mst_weight) {
                return numeric_limits<int>::max();
            }
            m_mst.push_back(edge);
            m_graph->union_vu(v,u);
        }
    }
```

`Edge` is:

```
class Edge{
public:
    Edge(int v_e, int u_e, int w){
        v = v_e;
        u = u_e;
        weight = w;
    }

    int get_node(){ return v; }
    int get_opposite_node(int k){
        if ((k==v) || (k==-1)) return u;
        else return v;
    }

    int v, u, weight;
};
```

Question: is there some more efficient way of checking if `Edge e` is in `vector<Edge> path` than they way defined in `bool MSTPath::m_in_path`? Or, more generally, maybe more efficient way of building `m_edges` and `m_mst` from `m_all_edges` and `path`?

Comment: Looking up in an unsorted vector is a O(N) complexity thing. You might want to put your edges to the `std::map` where lookup is O(LogN) or the `std::unordered_map`, where lookup is O(1). Former solution would required defining `operator<` for your `Edge`, and the latter would require defining hasing function and equality operator.

Comment: There's a lot of passing by value going on in this code. If you pass a `vector` by value you're not only getting all the overhead of constructing a new `vector` but of copying its contents as well. On top of this your range based `for` loops are also making copies of the `Edge` objects rather than referencing the ones inside the `vector`.

Comment: @Fibbles, yes, I realize that... Originally this was Python code that did not have so much passing by value. I had to translate it to C++, but, since I am relatively new to C++, I am not sure how to actually do it in "proper C++" way. So, if I pass `vector` by reference instead and change range based `for` for some pointer-based `for`, would it be better?

Comment: @Valeria It depends on your intent but at a glance I'd say pass the `vector` as a reference or const reference if it shouldn't be modified. E.g. `void foo(const vector<Edge>& bar);` The range based for loops just need to be changed to references or const references as well. E.g `for (Edge& e : path) { }`